# props.setAttributes results in "Maximum update depth exceeded."

Tags: block-editor

I really have hard time to understand react. I try to find headings in my blocks and put them in a constant. So far so good. I can confirm this works when I do a console.info(headings) after I found them in the blocks.

Now I try to save this array as an attribute. It does not matter if I define one in registerBlockType first or if I just try to set them with

props.setAttributes( { headings: headings } );

If I do so, I get this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

So I think this is some kind of recursion. But why does this happen? If I remove props.setAttributes it works but of course I don't have any attribute I get set my heading from.

```
registerBlockType( 'simpletoc/toc', {
    title: __( 'SimpleTOC', 'simpletoc' ),
    icon: listulicon,
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        headings: {
            type: 'array'
        },
    },
    edit: function ( props ) {
        const headings = find_headings( props );
        console.info(headings)
        props.setAttributes( { headings: headings } );

        return <Toc {...props} />;
    },
    save: function ( props ) {
        return <Toc  {...props} />;
    },
} );

function Toc( props ) {
    return <p className={ props.className }>
            <h2 class="simpletoc-title">{ __( 'Table of Contents', 'simpletoc' ) }</h2>
            <ul class="simpletoc">
                { props.headings }
            </ul>
            </p>;
}

function find_headings ( props ){

    const data = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' );
    const blocks = data.getBlocks();
    const headings = blocks.map( ( item, index ) => {
        if ( item.name === 'core/heading' ) {
            var slug = '';
            var hashslug = '';
            var blockId = ( item.clientId );

            slug = item.attributes.content;
            //wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).updateBlockAttributes( blockId, { anchor: slug } );
            hashslug = '#' + slug;

            return <li><a href={hashslug}>{item.attributes.content}</a></li>;
        }
    } );

    return {headings};
}
```

Comment: Try checking if the headings you're setting are any different from the headings you already have

Comment: What do you mean by "already" have? The attributes are empty and I want to set them. Or isn't this how it works? And it does not explain the "recursion".

Comment: Or do you mean that I have an array but I need DOM elements? SOuld I try to save it as a list items? Maybe as a string?

Comment: Or do you mean, that I need to store the headings from the editor into that array? But why?

Comment: Ok, so I tried to save <li>test</li> to the attribute and still the same error. I don't understand it. Sorry. I read about attributes but it seems that type "array" is not part of any tutorial.

Comment: Even if i change my function to this it has the same error: 

function find_headings ( props ){

 const data = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' );
 const blocks = data.getBlocks();
 const headings = blocks.map( ( item, index ) => {
  if ( item.name === 'core/heading' ) {
   return item;
  }
 } );
 return {headings};
}

This has to be a fundamental missunderstanding on how attributes work.

Comment: Using raw dom nodes is not the solution here, as I said, you have an infinite loop. Setting the attributes updates the component so it asks for the edit component, which updates the attribute, which updates the component so it asks for the edit component which updates the attribute... etc. As I said earlier, if the attribute is already the same, don't set it. E.g. don't set the attribute to 2 if the attribute already has the value 2. Check its current value first

Comment: Keep in mind that right now i'm being speculative on the correct method of updating that attribute. Your best bet for finding out the canonical method of doing this is probably asking in a gutenberg github issue

Comment: Well I tried to do this: 
  if ( headings != props.headings ) {
   props.setAttributes( { headings: headings } );
  }

But it does not help. I will ask in the gutenberg github repository. Thank you very much for your help so far. I

Comment: Posted it here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gutenberg-props-setattributes-results-in-maximum-update-depth-exceeded/#new-topic-0

Comment: I'd recommend the official GitHub repo instead: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/new/choose

Comment: Done https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/21712

Comment: Looking at your GH version of the code, I notice you're not storing data in the attribute, you're storing a full component tree. I doubt this is related to your problem, but, it is very inefficient, and will very  likely cause you new problems. Store the headings themselves, the data itself in the attributes, not react components, e.g. `[ 'heading1', 'heading2' ]` etc not `<p>heading 1</p><p>heading 2</p>`. Avoid storing HTML or react components if you can store the raw data that's used to create them

Comment: Yes, I do that because it is not just that. I also need a level (h2, h3, h4) and the content. So in the end it will be an array of data and I thought it is easier to the the dom elements.  

I still don't understand why I can't just store any data in an attribute and get it in the edit and save functions without getting that error described here. I got no reply from the Gutenberg team

Comment: That attribute needs to be serialised in some way as JSON, when you first load up the editor it'll load up all the attributes from the block as it's saved in the content. I don't see how React component instances can work like that. It's a bit like trying to store a jQuery carousel in post meta, doesn't really work. So you should use a JS data structure such as an object or nested array instead of react components. As for the GB team, the people there are more knowledgeable but the bandwidth vs incoming is lower. You'll need to be patient

Comment: My guess here is that in your edit property, you are calling props.setAttribute() on every render. This will cause a re-render in which it will be called again. This is a loop that will never end - hence the errors